# Ruling on Smoking Marijuana

Tags: sunni, smoking

Assalamu Alaiku wa  Rahmatullahi Ta'ala wa barakatuhu! Tafseer I was wondering what the rulings on smoking cigarettes and Indian hemp is, statistics shows that the rate that which youth consume these drugs is alarming and several researches have also proven that such drugs have physical n psychological problem which could result to so many social problems. More so, people that smoke cannabis said they get high aftersmiking, also the smoke emanating from ciggerret is malodorous which might hurt passer by or person next to you. Also the prophet said any thing hermful to your health is also Haram. Pls somebody should assist me with a better answer because am doubtful

Answer (score 0):

Salaam brother.

Here is what **Quran** and some **scholars** say:

- Allah, جل جلاله, says in Quran: “Don't throw yourself into danger by your own hands...” (el-Bakara 2/195).
- Shaykh Qaradawi, Egyptian scholar, believes it is no longer a place to discuss, since we know the health risks. Here is a quotation ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20080213192447/http://www.islamonline.net/servlet/Satellite?pagename=IslamOnline-English-Ask_Scholar/FatwaE/FatwaE&cid=1119503548726)) :

> ... They [scholars] all agree that whatever is proved to be harmful to
>   the body and mind is prohibited, yet they differ whether this ruling
>   applies to smoking...Our inclination to consider smoking prohibited
>   does not mean that it is as grave as major sins like adultery,
>   drinking alcohol or theft...
>
> We will report the opinion of some Muslim scholars, namely that the
>   ruling on indirect gradual harm is equal to that of direct immediate
>   harm, which is prohibition. If a substance has an immediate effective
>   poisonous effect and another substance has a slow effective poisonous
>   effect, they are both equally prohibited. Thus, the difference among
>   the scholars of fatwa over the prohibition or permissibility of
>   smoking tobacco is relative to their acquaintance with its
>   harmfulness.
>
> In reply to those who wonder how tobacco, which is just a plant, can be deemed prohibited without a legal text (from the Qur’an or the Sunnah) as proof, we say that the Lawgiver (Allah) does not have to provide a text for each case of prohibition.

- There is a PubMed/WHO resource addressing the prohibition of smoking by Al-Azhar University figures ([here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1360407/#ref16) and a WHO report in 2003).

Here is what I **personally** do: (**Thought based**)

I look at each action's short term and long term effects. Also if possible match it with a tafseer from Quran. 
Regarding this special topic, smoking and what is being smoked!, I'd suggest look at the medical research first. ANY kind of smoking is proven to be damaging to your body, specially lungs,which the organ will talk about it on the judgement day. 
So, here is your call:
Do you wanna "enjoy" the moment and get high/smoke?
I would say no since it damages me in three ways:
-short term: some of my friends and family may get upset or people around me may get hurt. 
- long term: increase the chance of getting cancer significantly and more on health issues. 
- Aakherah: My body will say I damaged and hurt it. I guess I'd have enough to deal with at that time that I wouldn't need another one.